# Codename One android build failing

Tags: java, android, build, codenameone

I tried to send my `Codename One` application to the build servers to build an android application, but it keeps failing. Everything works well on the emulator with no errors. The only problem is when I try to send the project to the build servers. Here is the error log. How can I fix this?

```
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android/gradle-2.11/bin/gradle assembleDebug -  -no-daemon --stacktrace --info To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.11/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Starting daemon process: workingDir = /home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon/2.11, daemonArgs: [/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java, -XX:MaxPermSize=512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx2048m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant, -cp, /home/ec2-user/android/gradle-2.11/lib/gradle-launcher-2.11.jar, org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon, 2.11]
Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon/2.11 Command: /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/ec2-user/android/gradle-2.11/lib/gradle-launcher-2.11.jar    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.11
Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
An attempt to start the daemon took 0.889 secs.
Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1668, address=[03f42828-ace4-482d-a252-c6948768b51e port:34287, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=2313a84a-24c5-475e-92ee-bfe642e21a4b,javaHome=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon,pid=1668,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request BuildAndStop{id=108a736a-2906-4e54-8f6e-53dfa3a8c086.1, currentDir=/tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication}.
Received result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@d554c5f from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1668, address=[03f42828-ace4-482d-a252-c6948768b51e port:34287, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=2313a84a-24c5-475e-92ee-bfe642e21a4b,javaHome=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon,pid=1668,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be starting).
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 1668). The daemon log file: /home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon/2.11/daemon-1668.out.log
Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=2313a84a-24c5-475e-92ee-bfe642e21a4b,javaHome=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon,pid=1668,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/master/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'MyApplication']
Evaluating root project 'MyApplication' using build file '/tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/build.gradle'.
Compiling build file '/tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/build.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
Compiling build file '/tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/build.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.

Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/19.0.0/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/17.0.0/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/18.1.1/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/19.0.2/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/18.1.0/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/auto/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/webdriver/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/admob_ads_sdk/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-   sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/market_licensing/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/gcm/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/simulators/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services_fit_preview/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/play_billing/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/analytics_sdk_v2/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services_froyo/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/play_licensing/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/gapid/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/support/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/armeabi-v7a/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19-1/package.xml
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location '/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected '/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19')
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-13/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-12/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-15/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-23/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-14/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-5/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-21/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-6/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-13/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-4/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-11/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-7/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-9/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-8/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-18/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_gdk-google-19/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-24/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-10/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-3/package.xml
Parsing /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-22/package.xml
Using incremental javac compilation.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Not using incremental javac compilation.
Using incremental javac compilation.
Not using incremental javac compilation.
Using incremental javac compilation.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'assembleDebug' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':preBuild', task ':preDebugBuild', task  ':checkDebugManifest', task ':preReleaseBuild',task ':prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library', task ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library', task ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library', task ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library', task ':prepareDebugDependencies', task ':compileDebugAidl', task ':compileDebugRenderscript', task ':generateDebugBuildConfig', task ':mergeDebugShaders', task ':compileDebugShaders', task ':generateDebugAssets', task ':mergeDebugAssets', task ':generateDebugResValues', task ':generateDebugResources', task ':mergeDebugResources', task ':processDebugManifest', task ':processDebugResources', task ':generateDebugSources', task ':incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard', task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac', task ':compileDebugNdk', task ':compileDebugSources', task ':prePackageMarkerForDebug', task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug', task ':mergeDebugJniLibFolders', task ':transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug', task ':processDebugJavaRes', task ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug', task ':validateDebugSigning', task ':packageDebug', task ':zipalignDebug', task ':assembleDebug']
Creating In-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin: MaxSize{878900}
Creating In-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin: MaxSize{6500}
Creating In-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin: MaxSize{21900}
Creating In-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin: MaxSize{4300}
:preBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:preBuild
Skipping task ':preBuild' as it has no actions.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.013 secs.
:preDebugBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:preDebugBuild
Skipping task ':preDebugBuild' as it has no actions.
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
:checkDebugManifest (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:checkDebugManifest
Executing task ':checkDebugManifest' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due  to:
Task has not declared any outputs.
:checkDebugManifest (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.006 secs.
:preReleaseBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:preReleaseBuild
Skipping task ':preReleaseBuild' as it has no actions.
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
Invalidating in-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin
Invalidating in-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
Invalidating in-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin
Invalidating in-memory cache of /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
Executing task ':prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library' (up-to-date check took 0.035 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main])  completed. Took 0.191 secs.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library
Executing task ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library' (up-to-date check took 0.002 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.243 secs.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library
Executing task ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library' (up-to-date check took 0.006 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.191 secs.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library
Executing task ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library' (up-to-date check took 0.003 secs) due to:
 No history is available.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
 Run with --debug option to get more log output.
*Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getPackageFromManifest(VariantConfiguration.java:999)
at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getOriginalApplicationId(VariantConfiguration.java:780)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$ConfigAction$_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy:167)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$ConfigAction$_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:136)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:114)
at  com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig_Decorated.getBuildConfigPackageName(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:458)
at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:166)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:456)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator.validate(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:277)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 9.892 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException:     org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build4588544765602326489xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1668, address=[03f42828-ace4-482d-a252-c6948768b51e port:34287, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=2313a84a-24c5-475e-92ee-bfe642e21a4b,javaHome=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon,pid=1668,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
```

Here are the Build hints i added:
 1. javascript.googlemaps.key=JavaScript_KEY
 2. ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"My_ios_Key"];
 3.android.xapplication=

Comment: Did you change the project package name or refactor it after creation?
Did you add any build hints that might have impacted this? Did you change the project classpath?

Comment: I added build hints and the Google-maps cn1 library. How can I fix this.

Comment: What build hints did you add? Please edit the question above and list them. Then post a comment here so I get notified of the edit. One of those changes must have broken the manifest XML

Comment: Fixed spelling and punctuation

Comment: Here is my third build hint                     android.xapplication=<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY"/>

Comment: i have found the solution,the problem is that i made a mistake when adding the build hints .the solution was to delete and re-add the build hints making sure that there are no errors this time.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution,the problem is that i made a mistake when adding the build hints .the solution was to delete and re-add the build hints making sure that there are no errors this time.thanks for the help